# React Native Fabric Component: How to call native method on iOS via Native Commands?

Tags: react-native

I created the RTNCenteredText – New Architecture's Fabric native component (testing it with project using React Native 0.71.4) based on [this page](https://reactnative.dev/docs/the-new-architecture/pillars-fabric-components). Additionally this component implements native command named `trigger`. The method was created according to the information available [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/new-architecture-library-intro#migrating-off-dispatchviewmanagercommand).

While `trigger` method works fine on Android (it's possible to catch its call via `receiveCommand` method of the `CenteredTextManager` class), it doesn't work on iOS.

The applied approach is using the `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD` macro in `RTNCenteredTextManager` (extending `RCTViewManager`), like:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(trigger:(nonnull NSNumber *)reactTag) {
    NSLog(@"*** Native method triggered");
}
```

Next exporting native commands in the `RTNCenteredTextNativeComponent.ts` file:

```
...

interface NativeCommands {
  trigger: (
    viewRef: React.ElementRef<ComponentType>
  ) => void;
}

export const Commands: NativeCommands = codegenNativeCommands<NativeCommands>({
  supportedCommands: ['trigger'],
});
```

And calling it in the `App.tsx` file:

```
this.log("Trigger native method");
if(this.ref) {
    this.log("Reference is not null " + this.ref);
    Commands.trigger(this.ref);
} else {
    this.log("Reference null");
}
```

Eventually the app produces these logs:

```
*** Fabric component initWithFrame
*** Fabric component updateProps
[javascript] [*** Capturing reference ref: [object Object] this.ref: undefined
[javascript] [*** Capturing reference ref: [object Object] this.ref: [object Object]
*** Fabric component updateProps
[javascript] [*** Trigger native method
[javascript] [*** Reference is not null [object Object]
```

So there is a missing `*** Native method triggered via Manager` log even though native command seems to be called correctly by the JS code.

Also I tried `RTNCenteredText` (using `RCTRTNCenteredTextViewProtocol`) implementing the `trigger` method but it doesn't work either, like:

```
- (void)trigger {
    NSLog(@"*** Fabric component trigger called directly");
}
```

Please see my [repository](https://github.com/damianzdunekgecko/RNNewArchitectureNativeCommands) reproducing the issue.

Possibly I miss an important detail or just misunderstand the concept of calling native methods of Fabric components. So I'd be grateful for pointing the proper approach out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution. I had to add the following method to *RTNCenteredText.mm*:

```
- (void)handleCommand:(const NSString *)commandName args:(const NSArray *)args {
    NSString *TRIGGER = @"trigger";
    if([commandName isEqual:TRIGGER]) {
        [self trigger];
    }
}
```

Comment: how to call native method in fabric like getText(), onTextChanged(), onClick() for android in kotlin.